# mysql database chained tables denormalization

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, denormalization

I have a design issue with db denormalization.
I'm making a relatively large database and need to optimize it a much as possible.

Here is a very simplified model of the issue.
All the tables from the picture a chained, and with a normalized database to get for example all the users from a specific country I have to join all the tables. That is cca 250 countries x cca 12000 cities x cca 625000 regions x ? addresses x ? users... In short that is a lot of joining, which takes a long time.

What I want to do, is to make the `country_id` redundant in the `user` table, so I can get the same query without any joining.

The question is, what is the best practice to keep consistency in such a model (btw. using MySql)?

One way and probably fastest is to ensure consistency on the application level, when inserting/updating/deleting data.

Other is stored procedures, which I really see no advantages. They ensure consistency only if directly called. The consistency breaks if you want to do some changes without the procedures.

I have also been looking at triggers... not really sure how to implement it, and how much would I gain in performance.

Anyway, it would be preferable to ensure consistency on the db level.

Any advice?

[image: Sample model]

Answer (score 6):

> All the tables from the picture a chained, and with a normalized
>   database to get for example all the users from a specific country I
>   have to join all the tables.

You have to join all the tables, because you use surrogate keys (id numbers), not because the tables are "normalized". Using surrogate keys like id numbers has nothing to do with normalization.

Natural keys and foreign key constraints is all you need to solve your problem.

The easiest way to see how this works is to start with full data, and work completely backwards. Assume all the data is correct.

```
addr_id  street           street_num       region    city          country
--
1        Babukiaeeva      3a               10000     Zagreb        Croatia
2        Riva             16               51000     Rijeka        Croatia 
3        Andrije Hebranga 2-4              10000     Zagreb        Croatia
4        Andrijeviaeeva   2               110000     Zagreb        Croatia
```

To record facts like "Region '10000' is associated with the city 'Zagreb' in the country 'Croatia'", create a new table, and populate it from this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT region, city, country from addresses;
```

Table will look like this.

```
Table: regions
Primary key: {region, city, country}

region   city      country
--
10000    Zagreb    Croatia
51000    Rijeka    Croatia
110000   Zagreb    Croatia
```

Then set a foreign key reference.

```
ALTER TABLE addresses 
ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY        (region, city, country) 
               REFERENCES regions (region, city, country);
```

To record facts like "City 'Zagreb' is in country 'Croatia'", create a new table, populate it from this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT city, country from regions;
```

Table will look like this.

```
Table: cities
Primary key: {city, country}

city      country
--
Zagreb    Croatia
Rijeka    Croatia
```

Then set a foreign key reference.

```
ALTER TABLE regions 
ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY       (city, country) 
               REFERENCES cities (city, country);
```

Repeat for countries.  The tables countries, cities, and regions are all key, so they're in 5NF. (They can't have any non-key dependencies, because they have no non-key columns.)  In the context of a large area, like all of Europe, it's likely that the table of addresses is also in 5NF.

It terms of query performance it's likely to run rings around your current schema, because it needs no joins.

You'll probably want to use `ON UPDATE CASCADE`; you might *not* want to cascade deletes, though.

Comment: this is a full redundancy approach. i think its better not to use composit keys for performace reasons. but still, im not convinced this is the way to do it, since it duplicates everything/everywhere. i think ill go with the materialized view approach in the end

Comment: "Redundant" is a technical term in relational theory; it doesn't have anything to do with storing foreign keys. (That's what foreign keys are for.) *These* composite keys eliminate *all* the joins. In most cases, this kind of schema will perform faster than 3 or 4 joins.  I've run tests like this that performed 200 times faster. You should test performance before you commit to either this schema or to a materialized view.

Comment: Yes, they eliminate joins, that is right... but they duplicate a lot of data (all "lower" keys in each table), and there is the presistancy problem. Composit keys have a lower perfomance (in MySql at least), so I think its better to intruduce a new incremented ID, and make the composition UNIQUE. But, anyway: I like the materialized view approach better that this. There is still a persistancy problem, but at least there is no redundancy in "original" tables

Comment: Composite keys have marginally slower performance *in joins*. But when you use natural keys in your schema, you eliminate *all* the joins. And foreign keys are *keys*; that's what you're *supposed* to store in multiple tables in a relational database. If anything deserves to be called "full redundancy", it's a materialized view, which duplicates *every bit* of the data. (And MySQL doesn't support materialized views anyway.)  Mock up both schemas, generate 10 million rows of data, and *test* the performance and disk space usage.

Comment: Ok, I agree. Except, materialized view doesn't have to duplicate everything. I use them to store "everything else" that the original table doesn't have, and do 1-to-1 join between the two. True, MySQL doesn't support them out-of-the-box, but materialized views are really all about concept not implementation. As for MySQL, a table and a couple of triggers can do the work just fine. The real advantage I'm referring to is keeping the "original" model clean and without redundancy. Simple remove the view and all denormalization is gone, and you are left with a 3NF schema

Comment: Btw. disk space is not a problem, I'm just looking for speed

Comment: "The real advantage I'm referring to is keeping the "original" model clean and without redundancy. Simple remove the view and all denormalization is gone, and you are left with a 3NF schema." But the other schema has no denormalization to remove, and it's in 5NF. And isn't your view going to simply reproduce the final table anyway? Seems like an odd decision.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - is it really too slow? 
Have you tried it? 
Do you hava an app where you dump all users (why?) or are you fetching a single/few users now and then. Since you have primary keys on all those ids, the retrieval shouldn't be that slow, there is a B-tree in the background after all.

Secondly, I wouldn't normalize on the street **number** level, you'll hardly get any benefits from that, and you'll probably end up having an almost 1:1 relationship between user and an address. So, move your street number to the client, or you can even move the entire address table to the user. I would probably move the region table also to the client (these are city regions?) and end up with user, city and country tables.

Then you'd have two joins, if that is still too slow, you can put the redundant country key (or, since we're denormalizing - country name) in the users. I'd use **triggers** to maintain integrity, more precisely you'll have to write: insert and update triggers  (update needs to fire only when regionId/cityId changes), and an update trigger on country (if you have country name in the user table) in the unlikely event that the country's name changes.

Performance-wise, you wouldn't gain, but lose with triggers, but I suppose that inserts and updates on the user table are not so frequent that you'd notice it at all.

Finally, since you didn't explain in detail the nature and size of you (web?) app, just a reminder that you might want to also consider/include other optimizations technologies outside the relational databases (caches, no-sql dbs, etc.).

Comment: Address is used for a few things, not just users... so I can't move it into the user table. Yes regions are city regions. They should also stay independent, since they are used in a lot of places (more than cities). Ok, I'm using triggers with the mentioned materialized view approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a lot of joining assuming you are not trying to denormalize all your data.

On the other hand, most people just have an address table, or (gasp!) keep the address information in the user table.  How many countries/ cities are you expecting to support, vs how many users?

Comment: As I said, it is a simplified model. This kind of structure is needed. As for the number of records, you have to be able so register from pretty much anywhere in the world, so the figures from the post pretty much summon it. How many users, hard to predict... anyway it has to be able to handle few hundred thousand users. Also to mention, that a lot of queries are country specific, so to join everything again and again seems too much

Comment: Then have a countryID in the users table, and a StateID, and a ... etc. Unless you require the heirarchy for some complex business purposes, I'd strongly recommend avoiding it.

Comment: Ok, but the question is how to ensure consistency is such a model, not really about using it or not

Comment: Data consistency should not have any sort of issues with this.  If you are talking about maintaining consistency between cities and countries, you certainly could have a FK in your city table to your country, but you need to determine if that's necessary.  What are the business requirements for enforcing this sort of thing?

Comment: Consistency example: user changes his address -> country_id needs to update, also when country_id in city is changed -> country_id in user should update. Second is a stupid example, but as I said it is a simplified model. As for business logic, it is an ordering system, address details need a deep structure for a lot of uses. Also a big amount of queries require only the top level id (in this case country_id), so I think denormalizing would speed up things a lot

Comment: If you insist on giving us a simplified model, you should be ready for simplified responses.